# Form Edit on Table Click

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and I am attempting to edit table data. I do not want to use a grid editor due to 508 compliance (and client preference).  The preferred functionality is to click on a row and a form is populated with the row data.

The problem that I am having is when I edit data in the form it automatically updates the table data.  I have separate $scope variables for the table data and the form data so I am confused as to why this is happening.  This is causing all edits to automatically be saved.  See below for a jsfiddle with a simplified table of my issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/sknnw5wk/

Ignore code, just in so SO does not complain about JSFiddle link, all code is in JSFiddle

```
$scope.editData = function (rowId) {
    'use strict';

    $scope.currentEditId = rowId;
    $scope.managementBaselineEdit = $scope.formData.managementBaseline.operations[rowId];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid that behaviour by making a copy of selected object ie:

```
$scope.managementBaselineEdit = angular.copy($scope.formData.managementBaseline.operations[rowId]);
```

please see working demo here

http://jsfiddle.net/cq7v5p4o/